# How to access columns of a joined table

Tags: php, yii2

I have a query that should return a result from a table joined with another table, I also have a loop that loops through the said result and writes data into XML. I had no problem with accessing primary table columns but I can't find a way to get to the joined table columns.

I have tried accessing it like `$job->$career_company->title` instead of `$job->title`, since that's the only answer I found but it still does not work.

my query

```
 $model = Career::find()
            ->joinWith('contact0')
            ->where(['not', ['responsible_person' => '']])
            ->where(['>=', 'valid_until', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))))])
            ->innerJoin('career_company', 'career_company_id = career_company.id')
            ->all();
```

using the data

```
<?php foreach ($model as $job) { ?>
    <JobadType>
        <?= $job->$career_company->title ?>
    </JobadType>
<?php } ?>
```

The error given to me is: 
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Undefined variable: career_company

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should notice is `<?= $job->$career_company->title ?>`.

What looks at the first glance or anyone will assume is that you are trying to call a relation and then accessing its field, and if that would have been the case it should rather be `$job->career_company->title` **without a `$`** sign. but you are not accessing a relation here you are using `innerJoin` on `career_company` and trying to access it via `$job->$career_company` which is wrong.

### Make your mind

You have 2 options

1. **Use the `innerJoin()` to join the table manually**

   - Join the table manually.
   - Specify the columns from the joined table.
   - Define a public property in the `Career` model with that name.
   - Add the field in the `safe` rules in the `Career` model.

The last 2 options above are optional in case you are using `->asArray()->all()` with the query to return the results as array rather than the model instance.

2. **Define relation and use `innerJoinWIth`**

   - Define a relation for the `career_company` say, `careerCompany`.
   - Use `innerJoinWith` to join the relation via inner join.
   - Use it the way you were trying above `$job->careerCompany->title`.

### Query Building

Since we don't have any model provided so I would go with the first option that you are using i.e `innerJoin`

- You need to add the columns to the `->select([column_1,column2])` clause for the relational table fields, either use `*` to select all columns from both the tables or mention them inside the array one by one.
- You are overdoing things in the where clause `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))))`, it should be `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('NOW -1 week'))` instead.
- After doing both of the above your query should look like below

```
 $model = Career::find()
     ->alias('c')
     ->select(['c.*', 'cc.title as career_title'])
     ->joinWith('contact0')
     ->where(['not', ['c.responsible_person' => '']])
     ->where(
         ['>=', 'c.valid_until', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('NOW -1 week'))]
     )
     ->innerJoin('career_company cc', 'c.career_company_id = cc.id')
     ->all();
```

- Now you need to define the field inside the model `Career` so go into your model and define a property `public $career_title` i used the alias for the column because it may be a possibility that you have the same column with the name `title` in the `Career` model/table.
- Then update the rules by listing the field as `safe`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...//other rules
        [['career_title'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

Now go to your view where you are creating the XML, and change the code to

```
<?php foreach ($model as $job) { ?>
    <JobadType>
        <?= $job->career_title?>
    </JobadType>
<?php } ?>
```